# How to in-place sort each sublist of a list in python

Tags: python

I have a list of integers as such:

```
[[12, 62, 49, 17, 99, 33, 47, 94, 58, 97, 75, 9], [46, 86, 95, 61, 80, 96, 14, 3, 
43, 2, 22, 83], [54, 57, 52, 32, 87, 15, 18, 39, 8, 90, 56, 23, 84], [82, 30, 26, 
31, 88, 37, 45, 79, 77, 66, 40, 51, 72]]
```

And I want a list back but each sublist is sorted in place like this:

```
[[9, 12, 17, 33, 47, 49, 58, 62, 75, 94, 97, 99], [2, 3, 14, 22, 43, 46, 61, 80,
83, 86, 95, 96], [8, 15, 18, 23, 32, 39, 52, 54, 56, 57, 84, 87, 90],[26, 30, 31, 
37, 40, 45, 51, 66, 72, 77, 79, 82, 88]]
```

I thought about looping through each element and replacing it with the output of `element.sort()` but that returns `None` since it's in-place. Is there a lambda function to do this?

Comment: `for l in lists: l.sort()`? - `list.sort()` will perform an in-place sort of the lists directly.

Comment: This is the best answer here @birryree.  Why not put it as an answer.  Its simple and correct.  The Lambda answer uses indexes in what I think is a not very pythonic way.  The other answer does not sort in place. (He changed it so it does now!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f = lambda lst: [lst[i].sort() for i in range(len(lst))].count(None)
```

This returns a number of successfully sorted lists.